# Wordpress get_permalink - always return the first post instead of the parent page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.5.2

I have set a custom page 'myblog' as 'Posts page' in 'Reading Settings', but why I always get the first post article of 'myblog' instead of 'myblog' itself?

```
var_dump(get_permalink()); // "http://xxxx.com/myblog/hello-world/"
```

It should be:

```
"http://xxxx.com/myblog/"
```

Any idea why and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the permalink for your blog page (`page_for_posts`). Below has a couple conditionals checks for fallback, but really the call `get_permalink()` on the `page_for_posts` option is what you need.

```
function get_my_blogpage_permalink() {
    if( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {

        return get_permalink( get_option('page_for_posts' ) );

    } else {

        return home_url();

    } 
}

var_dump(get_my_blogpage_permalink());
```